FEM: can't set up absorbing boundary
I am trying to simulate the electric voltage distribution on a structure between lines with roughness.
The coordinates are like this file:
LERCoordList
First I use these packages:
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; Needs["FEMAddOns`"];

I have generated mesh using the first 100 of 10000 length unit in LERCoordList as boundarymesh with this code
LERMesh =  ToElementMesh@
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> 
    Flatten[{#[[2]], Reverse@#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]]}} &@#, 1], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[
      Partition[
       Range[Length[
         Flatten[{#[[2]], Reverse@#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]]}} &@#, 1]]], 
       2, 1], Flatten[{Table[2, Length@#[[2]] - 1], 3, 
        Table[1, Length@#[[1]] - 1], 3}]]}] &@Block[{Len = #}, 
 Select[#, #[[1]] <= Len &] & /@ LERCoordList] & @ 100

and result as below:
Show[#["Wireframe"], PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-10, 20}},ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ LERMesh


For me the quality of the mesh is good.
The boundary mesh is also generated with assigned element marker, with the code below they are visualized:
Show[{#["Wireframe"[ElementMarker == 3, 
  "MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Red]], #[
 "Wireframe"[ElementMarker == 2, 
  "MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Blue]], #[
 "Wireframe"[ElementMarker == 1, 
  "MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Green]]},PlotRange -> {{-1, 101}, {-10, 20}}, ImageSize -> Medium] &@LERMesh


Then, I use this mesh to simulate the voltage distribution with absorbing boundary condition. I want to set the condition that at x=0 or x=Len, V^(1,0)[x,y]==0. These are the approaches I tried:
Voltage =NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y], {x, y}] == 0,Derivative[1, 0][V][0, y] == 0,DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == 10, ElementMarker == 1],DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == 0, ElementMarker == 2]},V, {x, y} \[Element] #] &@LERMesh

with this error:
NDSolveValue::fembderiv: The expression (V^(1,0))[0,y]==0 given as a spatial boundary condition for the possibly automatically chosen finite element method should not have explicit derivatives of the dependent variables. NeumannValue should be used to specify spatial derivatives at the boundary.

and this:
Voltage =  NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y], {x, y}] == 0,      DirichletCondition[D[V[x, y], x] == 0, ElementMarker == 3],      DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == 10, ElementMarker == 1],      DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == 0, ElementMarker == 2]},     V, {x, y} \[Element] #] &@LERMesh

with this error:
NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in V$28374==0 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[V$28374==0,ElementMarker==3] needs to be linear.

Can anyone help me solving this?
Thank you.
